# Browse through XML tags using QDomElement

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have to parse xml file's with the following format:

```
<FirstTag>
    <SecondTag>
        <Attribute value="hello"/> 
    </SecondTag>
</FirstTag>
```

Now this is what I have:

```
QDomNode n = domElem.firstChild();
while(!n.isNull()){
  QDomElement e = n.toElement();
  if(!e.isNull()){
    if(e.tagName() == "FirstTag"){
      //secondtag???
    }
  }
n = n.nextSibling();
}
```

Now to my actual question: 
I want to access an attribute from SecondTag, how can I access that, because its a sub tag from FirstTag I cant access it in my current loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've missed that QDomNode has child nodes and a function childNodes() to get the children of a node.

So, if QDomNode n is pointing to the first element, rather than looking for just the first Child, get the child nodes of each element, checking for the right node name and then the child nodes of each child. To get the attribute, you'd do something like this:-

```
QString attribValue;
QDomNodeList children = n.childNodes();

QDomNode childNode = children.firstChild();
while(!childNode.isNull())
{
    if(childNode.nodeName() == "Attribute")
    {    // there may be multiple attributes
         QDomNamedNodeMap attributeMap = node.attributes();

         // Let's assume there is only one attribute this time
         QDomAttr item = attributeMap.item(0).toAttr();
         if(item.name() == "value")
         {
            attribValue = item.value(); // which is the string "hello"
         } 
    }       
}
```

This could be done with a recursive function, for each node and its children.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple XML doc, so try this. This code works as you want

```
QDomDocument doc("mydocument");
QFile f("G:/x.txt");
if (!f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    qDebug()  <<"fail";
if (!doc.setContent(&f)) {
    f.close();
    qDebug() <<"fail";
}
f.close();

QDomElement domElem = doc.documentElement();//FistTag here
QDomNode n = domElem.firstChild();//seconTag here
  QDomElement e = n.toElement();
  if(!e.isNull()){
      n = n.firstChild();//now it is attribute tag

      e = n.toElement();
        qDebug() << e.attribute("value") <<"inside" << e.tagName();
  }
```

Output: `"hello" inside "Attribute"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it that way. First use documentElement() then (on the returned object) search for the nested elements using elementsByTagName().